# Django annotate(Count('id')) generates wrong sql query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have following models

```py
class TagCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(TagCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tag')


class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Evaluation(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='evaluations')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='evaluations')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
```

When I run following script in django shell,

```py
pos = Position.objects.annotate(
    tag=F('evaluations__tags'), 
    tag_category=F('evaluations__tags__category'), 
    tag_cnt=Count('tag')
)

subquery = pos.filter(id=OuterRef('id'),
                      tag_category=OuterRef('tag_category')
                      ).order_by('-tag_cnt')[:3].values('tag')

qs = pos.filter(tag__in=Subquery(subquery))

for item in qs.values():
    print(item)
```

it gives result like following, for example.

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Director', 'tag': 8, 'tag_category': 2, 'tag_cnt': 4}
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Director', 'tag': 5, 'tag_category': 1, 'tag_cnt': 1}
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Director', 'tag': 7, 'tag_category': 1, 'tag_cnt': 3}
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Director', 'tag': 9, 'tag_category': 2, 'tag_cnt': 2}
```

`qs` gives what I wanted, but the problem rises if I annotate `count of rows per id` to `qs`. When I run following,

```py
final = qs.values('id').annotate(cnt=Count('id'))
```

`final` gives

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'cnt': 10}]>
```

which is not what I have expected. I hope `cnt` give '4' for this example, because `qs` has four rows with `id` 1. How should I change my orm code?

**EDIT**

What I ultimately want is to get filtered queryset of Position objects by `cnt` value like below, so I cannot use qs.count().

```py
Position.objects.annotate(cnt=Subquery(
    final.filter(id=OuterRef('id')).values('cnt'))
).filter(cnt=4)
```

**EDIT 2**

Here I attach sql queries generated by orm.

sql query for `qs`

```
SELECT
   "positions_position"."id",
   "positions_position"."name",
   "positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id" AS "tag",
   "positions_tag"."category_id" AS "tag_category",
   COUNT("positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id") AS "tag_cnt" 
FROM
   "positions_position" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "positions_evaluation" 
      ON ("positions_position"."id" = "positions_evaluation"."position_id") 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "positions_evaluation_tags" 
      ON ("positions_evaluation"."id" = "positions_evaluation_tags"."evaluation_id") 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "positions_tag" 
      ON ("positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id" = "positions_tag"."id") 
WHERE
   "positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id" IN 
   (
      SELECT
         U2."tag_id" AS "tag" 
      FROM
         "positions_position" U0 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "positions_evaluation" U1 
            ON (U0."id" = U1."position_id") 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "positions_evaluation_tags" U2 
            ON (U1."id" = U2."evaluation_id") 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "positions_tag" U3 
            ON (U2."tag_id" = U3."id") 
      WHERE
         (
            U0."id" = "positions_position"."id" 
            AND U3."category_id" = "positions_tag"."category_id"
         )
      GROUP BY
         U0."id",
         U2."tag_id" 
      ORDER BY
         COUNT(U2."tag_id") DESC LIMIT 3
   )
GROUP BY
   "positions_position"."id",
   "positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id",
   "positions_tag"."category_id"
```

sql query for `final`

```
SELECT
   "positions_position"."id",
   COUNT("positions_position"."id") AS "cnt" 
FROM
   "positions_position" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "positions_evaluation" 
      ON ("positions_position"."id" = "positions_evaluation"."position_id") 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "positions_evaluation_tags" 
      ON ("positions_evaluation"."id" = "positions_evaluation_tags"."evaluation_id") 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "positions_tag" 
      ON ("positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id" = "positions_tag"."id") 
WHERE
   "positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id" IN 
   (
      SELECT
         U2."tag_id" AS "tag" 
      FROM
         "positions_position" U0 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "positions_evaluation" U1 
            ON (U0."id" = U1."position_id") 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "positions_evaluation_tags" U2 
            ON (U1."id" = U2."evaluation_id") 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "positions_tag" U3 
            ON (U2."tag_id" = U3."id") 
      WHERE
         (
            U0."id" = "positions_position"."id" 
            AND U3."category_id" = "positions_tag"."category_id"
         )
      GROUP BY
         U0."id",
         U2."tag_id" 
      ORDER BY
         COUNT(U2."tag_id") DESC LIMIT 3
   )
GROUP BY
   "positions_position"."id"
```

GROUP BY clause in `final` seems weird. Why `GROUP BY "positions_position"."id", "positions_evaluation_tags"."tag_id", "positions_tag"."category_id"` is gone and only `GROUP BY "positions_position"."id"` remained?

Comment: I think you should count `qs.count()` it will give the total objects of the query set

Comment: @l.b.vasoya I need cnt value to be calculated in subquery, but count() can not be used in subquery, as I know.

Comment: see this link might help you https://www.kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#count

Answer (score 0):

In the Count pass the distinct=True argument i.e

```
tag_cnt=Count('tag', distinct=True)
```

Comment: That makes every `tag_cnt` in `qs` 1, which shouldn't be. `tag_cnt` represents how many specific Tag is attached to specific Position.